# Finding longest array in a three-dimensional array and returning a one-dimensional array that contains the largest array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

A method `public static int[] largestArray(int[][][]a)`

returns a single dimensional array that contains the largest array in the 3D array

Comment: What is your actual question? Your title looks like a homework problem. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to get the first element which matches your condition, you can try this code.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    int[][] arrI = arr[i];
    for(int j = 0; j < arrI.length; j++) {
        int[] arrJ = arr[j];
        if(arrJ.length > saved.length) {
            saved = arrJ;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I need to return the position (two elements) of the longest array from the three dimensional array given in the parameter

Comment: Than you can save the i and j parameters instead of arrJ and return them as an array.